# Chase auto-pay enrolled but don't remember doing so

Tags: credit-card, payment

I generally make it a rule to never allow automated payments.  This month I happened to notice that my Chase Freedom CC statement showed that I was enrolled in their auto payment program.  I called Customer Service to make sure and sure enough they were able to tell me the last four of my checking account number.

This is very disturbing as I would swear I never set it up because of my general adversity to such things as described above.  The CS associate said they could remove it, but given they already have that sensitive data, that I'm almost certain I did not provide, why bother?

I used to have a mortgage with Chase and the only thing that might have happened was that I agreed to an auto payment on the mortgage in order to get a preferred rate.  If this is the case, then how did it make it to my CC without my authorization?

1. Anyone else have this happen to them?
2. Is there any reasonable way for Chase to show me when and how I did this?

Comment: Was any money actually taken out of your bank account to pay the Chase credit card bill via the autopay option? Or did the monthly paper statement (or the card web site) indicate that you are enrolled in Autopay but no money has actually been taken out as yet, in which case the whole thing could be settled as a no-harm no-foul deal with the offending enrollment removed? In general, whether you pay your credit-card bill by paper check or on-line by EFT via the "Make a Payment" option offered on credit-card sites, your bank account number **will** become known to Chase.

Comment: By 'sensitive data" you mean your checking acct number? I could have the number of every parent my daughter babysat for. So what? I don't care for autopay, and would simply request they cancel it.

Comment: Chase and other banks would send an email to confirm an auto-pay enrollment. Check your email to see if you have ever received that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a long standing chase customer and have never been signed up for an autopay without specific consent.  They should be able to show you when and where you signed up for auto pay.  You may have inadvertently done it on the site.  They keep a log of all this stuff.  Ask for a supervisor if the rep will not answer your question.  If the call center doesn't answer your question, try a local branch of Chase.  The personal bankers there have access to all that stuff.

Comment: Actually, Chase was sued and settled a class-action suit for a similar behaviour. So if you were never signed up, doesn't mean that someone else wasn't.